# Ubuntu get python Phantomjs path

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, phantomjs

Hi I have a windows python script which uses selenium and phantonjs that I would want to run in a linux environment.

If the path below would refer to my windows environment. How would I refer it so that it picks the phantomjs after I must have installed it.

```
 driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=(os.path.abspath("phantomjs.exe")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to provide `executable_path` if *`phantomjs` executable is on the `PATH`* - meaning, if you can execute `phantomjs.exe` from the console.

Here is a [related blogpost with instructions](https://www.joecolantonio.com/2014/10/14/how-to-install-phantomjs/).

Comment: Thanks but thats for Windows , I want to run it in linux envrironment. How do I refer it in linux ?

Comment: @tagnihuguespascal the idea is the same - just put the `phantomjs` executable on `PATH` env variable.

Comment: Okay makes sense. Let me give that a try . Thanks